# First App Running issues using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, windows-10

I am learning Android Programming. Learning the basics using Android Studio
Mine is a simple Hello World program. I installed Android Studio on Windows 10. When I first run the emulator I get following error details

```
eglMakeCurrent failed
eglMakeCurrent failed
eglMakeCurrent failed
eglMakeCurrent failed
distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:2073 error 0x501
distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:2073 error 0x501
Error making draw context current
draw: Could not use program error=0x501
draw: Could not bind GL_ARRAY_BUFFER error=0x502
eglMakeCurrent failed
```

My emulator first showed "android" logo for about 15 mins. after some time it became blank. Help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply uncheck the checkbox "Use Host GPU" within the settings of the virtual device and it will start working again.

Comment: Where do you find these settings?